# Configure L2TP/IPSec so the user identity is passed to iptables rule

Tags: iptables, ipsec, passwd

Hi I'm pretty new to this so you'll have to be very explicit.

I set up L2TP/IPSec on CentOS so that I can VPN. User identities are stored in the `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets`, mainly because that's how things work in the installation script I used.

Now I want to write some rules to block certain sites based on the user. I tried:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -s badsite.com -m owner --uid-owner 100 -i eth0 -p tcp -s --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-destination http://myserver.com/blockedsitewarning
```

where 100 is an employee's unix account ID. But this won't work because of course the `chap-secrets` account is completely separate from the `passwd` account.

How would I configure L2TP/IPSec and/or iptables so that they will use the same authentication system and user identity? Please post actual configuration files rather than just abstract concepts or links to man pages. Thanks!!!

PS: I realize that this question was posted on other forums as well but on those forums it's been marked as "off topic" so I hope this forum will be better suited for it. If it is not, please refer me to the proper forum.

Comment: `chap-secrets`? Did you really set up IPSec, and not actually L2TP?

Comment: You are correct; this is IPSec over L2TP. Will update the description.

Comment: Possibly this could be the way (see section titled "Local user (PAM//etc/passwd) authentication")
https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/IPSEC_L2TP_vpn_with_Ubuntu_13.10.html

Comment: Unfortunately this solution uses openswan and doesn't seem to work for the native IPSec.

Comment: It's a solution for a completely different problem, and won't make `--uid-owner` work – it's just for authentication. (But I'm not sure what you mean by "native IPSec"?)

Comment: I suppose that it will use the usernames in passwd for the VPN users to log in with. And I was under the impression that the same user will be used in --uid-owner but I may be wrong. It could be that the user is the "currently logged in user" only. Or a local process. In which case my idea of filtering based on the VPN user is doomed. What do you think?

By "native" I mean it comes installed in centos as opposed to openswan which I have to install.